# How to make short code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can anybody help me to short this code with few lines?
I dont have an idea to get short this code.

```
    If TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P1.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P2.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P3.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P4.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P5.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P6.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P7.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
    ElseIf TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P8.Bounds) Then
        GOver.Visible = True
        GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could put all the `Bounds` in a `List` and then using `LINQ` `Any` to simplify your logic:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Rectangle)(New Rectangle() {P1.Bounds, P2.Bounds, P3.Bounds, P4.Bounds, P5.Bounds, P6.Bounds, P7.Bounds, P8.Bounds})
IF list.Any(Function(x) TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x)) THEN
    GOver.Visible = True
    GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
END IF
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine for the brevity. Question: Will yours evaluate all of the `IntersectsWith` before executing the inner code, or will first to return true short circuit to the inner code?

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK, The `Any` should return `True` when one instance is found `True` (short circuited)

Comment: Just satisfied my own curiosity with simple tests...Indeed both solutions run the tests in the order given, both will short circuit on first true result, and yours is faster by half. Nice!

Comment: @MrGadget nice test, that confirms the short circuit. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim HasIntersects As Boolean = True

With TBird.Bounds
    Select Case True
        Case .IntersectsWith(P1.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P2.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P3.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P4.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P5.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P6.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P7.Bounds)
        Case .IntersectsWith(P8.Bounds)
        Case Else
            HasIntersects = False
    End Select
End With

If HasIntersects Then
    GOver.Visible = True
    GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P1.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P2.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P3.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P4.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P5.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P6.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P7.Bounds) OrElse 
    TBird.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P8.Bounds) Then
    GOver.Visible = True
    GOver.Location = New Point(227, 79)
End If
```

Comment: How can I random that p1 up to p8? Where p1....p8 are picturebox (pipes like flappy bird) I did my best but no luck... Code that I used.

Comment: `code`Public Class Form1
     Dim pipes = 2
     Dim rn As New Random
 
 'pipes movement
 Private Sub ObsM_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ObsM.Tick
        Dim pipes As Integer = (rn.Next(1, 9))

        P1.Left = P1.Left - pspeed
        P2.Left = P2.Left - pspeed
        If P1.Left < 0 And P2.Left < 0 Then
            P1.Left = P1.Left + lpipes
            P2.Left = P2.Left + lpipes
        End If
        If P3.Left < 0 And P4.Left < 0 Then
            P3.Left = P3.Left + lpipes
            P4.Left = P4.Left + lpipes
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: create a new question